# Setting cache-control via Boto doesn't work

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm uploading the file via Boto. I'm also trying to set `Cache-Control` header as well. But it doesn't set after I looked at it in S3

Here's my code.

```
def upload(self, filename, filepath):
    k = Key(self.fusion_bucket)
    k.key = "%s/%s/%s" % (self.folder, get_current_date(), filename)
    k.set_contents_from_filename(filepath, policy='public-read')

    ext = filename.split(os.extsep)[1]
    k.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'video/%s' % (ext))
    k.set_metadata('Cache-Control', self.cache_header)

    return k.generate_url(expires_in=0, query_auth=False)
```

I can confirm that `self.cache_header` has value in it and it's public,max-age= 1864000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_metadata` sets the metadata in a local Python dict. You're looking for `set_remote_metadata` instead:

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html?highlight=set_remote_metadata#boto.s3.key.Key.set_remote_metadata